# How to persist SOAP Messages in MySQL Database - working with Axis Client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis, webservice-client

I am writing a java axis client, how could I persist raw xml into data base, till now I have found two ways of logging raw xml, but they are for console or to a file, but I need to persist each request and response into mysql database, where I could use connection as a user parameter.

here is what I have done already.

1. [log raw ws xml to console](http://www.coderanch.com/t/148794/java-Web-Services-SCDJWS/certification/Getting-Raw-Request-Response-XML)
2. [log raw ws xml to a file](http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/AxisClientConfiguration/ViewSOAPMessages)

Well I have found a solution, First we need to use the Custom handler as I mentioned earlier(1), we can set property in the message context
like

```
public class FedexWsHandler extends GenericHandler {

    public QName[] getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext context) {
    try {
        SOAPMessageContext smc = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
        SOAPMessage reqMsg = smc.getMessage();
        context.setProperty("req-msg", reqMsg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    return true;
    }

    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext context) {
    try {
        SOAPMessageContext smc = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
        SOAPMessage reqMsg = smc.getMessage();
        context.setProperty("res-msg", reqMsg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    return true;
    }

}
```

and then in out client we can get that property and do what ever you want to do, like

```
MyServiceLocator locator = new MyServiceLocator(); 
MyService service = locator.getMyService(); 
service.getResults("foo", "bar"); // call the service

// I want to get that message I have set in request and response handler methods
MessageContext ctx = locator.getCall().getMessageContext();
SOAPMessage reqMsg = (SOAPMessage) requestContext.getProperty("req-msg");         
SOAPMessage resMsg = (SOAPMessage) requestContext.getProperty("res-msg");
```

But it is not a safe way to do that as this is not **Thread Safe**. as per its [docs](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/client/Service.html#getCall%28%29)

.... so if any one can suggest me some better solution.

Comment: Is this for auditing purposes?

Comment: yes, to have the trace log of all the request and response messages shared.

Answer (score 0):

[JAXB Marshaller : StringWriter output has a truncated tag value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146217/jaxb-marshaller-stringwriter-output-has-a-truncated-tag-value)

Please have a look on the above post, you can convert the xml to java string and and than you can use any mysql data type which can hold your xml converted to string. you can use blob if the string in very large.