# JAXB Marshaller : StringWriter output has a truncated tag value

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb

I want to marshall a java object to xml string.
Therefore I have been given a schema from which I generate the JAXB classes.
There is a set method(corresponding to an element of type hexbinary in schema) where I have to set a string.
The string size is about 2566.
After setting data into the object via the setter methods, I call the marshaller passing stringWriter argument.

But on printing stringWriter, I see that it is truncated. I don't see the entire 2566 characters.

What is wrong? Any ideas?

Thanx!

**Update:**

I think I found the problem. I have to find a suitable title as my reasoning of the problem was wrong!! The problem is the following:
I have a "hexbinary" element in my schema. The generated class has a corresponding set/get method. To set the value I had used HexEncodeString method of apache commons package and realized that the marshaller shows 36383639 in the hexbinary tag for a String "hi" whose actual Hex encoding is 6869 :(  Thus, the problem is the xml after marshalling has a tag value with # of chars greater than the original and not getting truncated like I thought before!

Thanks to *Blaise Doughan*'s code. I have modified it and reproduced this problem.

First an example schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="Root">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:hexBinary" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

With this I generated the ObjectFactory class and Root class.
I had to modify the ObjectFactory class to include JAXBElement so that I can pass this to the Marshaller. With these I took the Demo class of Blaise Doughan and modified it as:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);      

    // The object factory
    ObjectFactory objFactory = new ObjectFactory();
    Root root = new Root();
    String str = new String("hi");
    String val = Hex.encodeHexString(str.getBytes());
    root.setString(str);
    root.setArr(val.getBytes());

        System.out.println("val="+val);
        System.out.println("getString ="+root.getString());
        System.out.println("getArr="+new String(root.getArr()));

        // Marshal the object to a StringWriter
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.example.com/schema.xsd");
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(objFactory.createRoot(root),stringWriter);
//      marshaller.marshal(root, stringWriter);

        // Convert StringWriter to String
        String xml = stringWriter.toString();
        System.out.println(xml);

        // Unmarshal the XML and check length of long String
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Root unmarshalledRoot = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        System.out.println(root.getString().length());
        System.out.println(root.getString());
        System.out.println(new String(root.getArr()).length());
        System.out.println(new String(root.getArr()));
    }

}
```

The output I get is:

```
val=6869
getString =hi
getArr=6869
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:Root xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schema.xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://example.com/root" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <string>hi</string>
    <arr>36383639</arr>
</ns3:Root>

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://example.com/root", local:"Root"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:631)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:236)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1038)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:467)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:448)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:200)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:194)
    at example.Demo.main(Demo.java:43)
```

Why is arr tag 36383639  and not 6869?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

In your sample code `val` is the hexBinary representation of `str.getBytes()`.  But the value you are setting on the `arr` property is the bytes from the hex encoded String.

```
String str = new String("hi");
String val = Hex.encodeHexString(str.getBytes());
root.setString(str);
root.setArr(val.getBytes());
```

I believe what you mean to do is the following:

```
String str = new String("hi");
String val = Hex.encodeHexString(str.getBytes());
root.setString(str);
root.setArr(str.getBytes());
```

Which will produce the following output

```
val=6869
getString =hi
getArr=hi
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <string>hi</string>
    <a>6869</a>
</root>
```

Put another way

```
    String str = new String("hi");
    System.out.print("String:  " + str);
    System.out.println(" hexBinary:  " + Hex.encodeHexString(str.getBytes()));
    String val = Hex.encodeHexString(str.getBytes());
    System.out.print("String:  " + val);
    System.out.println(" hexBinary:  " + Hex.encodeHexString(val.getBytes()));
```

Will output:

```
String:  hi hexBinary:  6869
String:  6869 hexBinary:  36383639
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I have not been able to reproduce the issue that you are seeing.  I am using a `String` size of `500000`.  Below is what I have tried (does this sample work for you?).   Is it possible that the truncation is due to the console you are writing the long String to?

**Demo**

```java
package forum12146217;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        // Build a long String
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int x=0; x<500000; x++) {
            stringBuilder.append("a");
        }
        Root root = new Root();
        root.setString(stringBuilder.toString());
        System.out.println(root.getString().length());

        // Marshal the object to a StringWriter
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.example.com/schema.xsd");
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(root, stringWriter);

        // Convert StringWriter to String
        String xml = stringWriter.toString();
        //System.out.println(xml);

        // Unmarshal the XML and check length of long String
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Root unmarshalledRoot = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        System.out.println(unmarshalledRoot.getString().length());
    }

}
```

**Root**

```java
package forum12146217;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private String string;

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
500000
500000
```

Comment: Could it be the nature of the string? As in the hexbinary value in that tag is  an objectoutputstream. I can update my question with that piece of code.

Comment: I pass the JAXBContext to the marshaller and not the XmlRootElement. The XJC generates an OnjectFactory class and I call the create method defined under  @XmlElementDecl which returns a JAXBElement<myClasstype> which is then passed to Marshaller. Only here does it gets messed up. How can I find the right place. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user907810 - If you adapt the code I provided with a String that matches your use case what results do you see?

Comment: Hi, thanks for such useful code tips. I have found out the correct place of the error. I can elaborate it under this post. Please see the update